# Why is a while loop needed around pthread wait conditions?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm learning pthread and wait conditions. As far as I can tell a typical waiting thread is like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
while(!condition)
     pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &m);
// Thread stuff here
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
```

What I can't understand is why the line `while(!condition)` is necessary even if I use `pthread_cond_signal()` to wake up the thread.

I can understand that if I use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` I need to test condition, because I wake up *all* waiting threads and one of them can make the condition false again before unlocking the mutex (and thus transferring execution to another waked up thread which should not execute at that point).
But if I use `pthread_cond_signal()` I wake up just *one* thread so the condition must be true. So the code could look like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &m);
// Thread stuff here
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
```

I read something about spurious signals that may happen. Is this (and only this) the reason? Why should I have spurious singnals? Or there is something else I don't get?

I assume the signal code is like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
condition = true;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond); // Should wake up *one* thread
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The real reason you should put pthread_cond_wait in a while loop is not because of spurious wakeup. Even if your condition variable did not have spurious wakeup, you would still need the loop to catch a common type of error. Why? Consider what can happen if multiple threads wait on the same condition:

```
Thread 1                         Thread 2           Thread 3
check condition (fails)
(in cond_wait) unlock mutex
(in cond_wait) wait
                                 lock mutex
                                 set condition
                                 signal condvar
                                 unlock mutex
                                                    lock mutex
                                                    check condition (succeeds)
                                                    do stuff
                                                    unset condition
                                                    unlock mutex
(in cond_wait) wake up
(in cond_wait) lock mutex
<thread is awake, but condition
is unset>
```

The problem here is that the thread must release the mutex before waiting, potentially allowing another thread to 'steal' whatever that thread was waiting for. Unless it is guaranteed that only one thread can wait on that condition, it is incorrect to assume that the condition is valid when a thread wakes up.

Comment: exactly. up-voted. this should get more attention than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

Suppose you don't check the condition. Then usually you can't avoid the following bad thing happening (at least, you can't avoid it in one line of code):

```
 Sender                             Receiver
locks mutex
sets condition
signals condvar, but nothing 
  is waiting so has no effect
releases mutex
                                    locks mutex
                                    waits. Forever.
```

Of course your second code example could avoid this by doing:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
if (!condition) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &m);
// Thread stuff here
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
```

Then it would certainly be the case that if there is only ever at most one receiver, and if `cond_signal` were the only thing that could wake it up, then it would only ever wake up when the condition was set and hence would not need a loop. nos covers why the second "if" isn't true.

Comment: I see, so an "if" is needed due to a logic reason (endless wait), but a while is actually needed due to implementation issues (spurious signals).

Comment: Yea when I first used the pthreads library I asked the same question.  I omitted checking a state variable and my program would signal before the wait occurred.  This is the entire point of the wait/signal functions.  To wait and signal on some mutex protected change in state of memory.