# POSIX: How can I suspend thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I know some trick with condition, but it is not helpful.

Suppose that I have infinite loop in my thread function. How can I suspend only this thread, not all process?

Comment: Depends on when or how you want it to resume.

Comment: What do you mean? I just want to suspend/resume thread by id.

Comment: @user1514958: Posix has no such function AFAIK. If it did, it would probably be called `pthread_suspend`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) or [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: aren't these things only in C++11? (question is tagged c++)

Comment: @saeedn: and what's the current C++ standard, given that this year is 2012? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop, its not too much to ask for the equivalent in c++, considering perhaps the OP cant use c++11 and the question is tagged posix. The Posix type is `pthread_cond_t`, here is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1136371/1158895

Comment: He can use boost for portability