# Let me make sure I understand C pthread mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I have a global variable `flag`, a function `this()`, and a function `that()`.  Now, `main()`, `this()` and `that()` all have occasions where they need to read and/or write `flag`.  To properly use a mutex I would need to:

1. declare a `pthread_mutex_t` and initialize it.
2. create threads for `this()` and `that()` and `pthread_join()` them because I want `main()` to wait on `this()` and `that()` to finish before exiting.
3. anywhere in the code, be it `main()`, `this()`, or `that()`, where `flag` is being read or written, call `pthread_mutex_lock()` then [read/write] `flag` then call `pthread_mutex_unlock()`

Is that correct?

I don't plan on doing this but if I want to check `flag` in an infinite loop in `main()` like this:

```
    while(flag != value)
        continue;
```

Where would you `lock()` and `unlock()` the mutex and would the other threads get a chance to access `flag` with `main()` being constantly all over it like that?

Comment: You'd want a pthread condition for that last loop.

Comment: Use pthread objects for what they are intended for. A mutex guards access to something (or things), while a condition variable is used to signal change in a predicate to one or more potential interested parties. Properly used in concert, the tasks you spell out are both elegant, and fairly trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - 2 - 3 - correct.

Now, if your write that loop, then

- as a consequence of 3, the main thread will hold the lock, and other threads won't be able to acquire the lock, so in effect, you created an infinite loop.
- if you don't lock, then it might not work, it depends on the CPU architecture (first of all, `flag` needs to be atomically updateable, and other cores need to see those changes. not all architectures guarantee this). Even if it works, it's still a busy wait loop, and shouldn't be used.

As Ben pointed out in his comment, you want to use condition variables for signaling (note: [Pthread and wait conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136371/pthread-and-wait-conditions))

> Where would you lock() and unlock() the mutex

As a thumb of rule, to minimize the contention, hold the lock as short as possible. This could be as simple as lock+read+unlock, but if the following sequence of operations depend on the fact that the flag shouldn't be changed, then keep the lock as long as needed.

Comment: Thank you.  That is more or less what I thought, just wanted to make sure I had the gist of it before making my first foray into mutexes.  I read and re-read the man pages and looked at several examples from various sources and at the end of it I still wasn't sure I had a handle on it.  @WhozCraig - It's heavy stuff for a novice, self-taught guy like me ;)