# Synchronising thread startup

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm running some code (simplified, but still breaking version below), which fails in ~1/3000 executions waiting for the first switch. What should happen is:

- `threads[0]` starts up and grabs the mutex
- `threads[0]` notifies `cond_main` so the main thread can create `thread[1]`
- `thread[1]` / `thread[0]` do some work waiting for each others' signals

Unfortunately it fails in `thread[0]` - the `cond.wait` ends with a timeout and raises an exception. How would I synchronise this, making sure that `cond_main` doesn't get signalled too early?

Ideally I'd like to pass a locked mutex from main thread and unlock it in the first spawned thread, but Ruby requires mutexes to be unlocked in the same thread - so this won't work.

Self-contained reproducer (doesn't make much sense on its own, but real work is stripped out):

```
def run_test
  mutex     = Mutex.new
  cond      = ConditionVariable.new
  cond_main = ConditionVariable.new
  threads   = []

  t1_done = false
  t2_done = false

  threads << Thread.new do
    mutex.synchronize do
      # this needs to happen first
      cond_main.signal
      cond.wait(mutex, 2)
      raise 'timeout waiting for switch' if !t2_done

      # some work
      t1_done = true
      cond.signal
    end
  end
  cond_main.wait(Mutex.new.lock, 2)

  threads << Thread.new do
    mutex.synchronize do
      cond.signal
      # some work
      t2_done = true
      cond.wait(mutex, 2)
      raise 'timeout waiting for switch' if !t1_done
    end
  end

  threads.map(&:join)
end

5000.times { |x|
  puts "Run #{x}"
  run_test
}
```

Tested on Ruby 2.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a while block to stop waiting if second thread finished (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136371/why-is-a-while-loop-needed-around-pthread-wait-conditions)):

```
def run_test
  mutex     = Mutex.new
  cond      = ConditionVariable.new
  cond_main = ConditionVariable.new
  threads   = []

  spawned = false

  t1_done = false
  t2_done = false

  threads << Thread.new do
    mutex.synchronize do
      while(!spawned) do
        cond.wait(mutex, 2)
      end
      raise 'timeout waiting for switch' if !t2_done

      # some work
      t1_done = true
      cond.signal
    end
  end

  threads << Thread.new do
    mutex.synchronize do
      spawned = true
      cond.signal
      # some work
      t2_done = true
      cond.wait(mutex, 2)
      raise 'timeout waiting for switch' if !t1_done
    end
  end

  threads.map(&:join)
end

50000.times { |x| 
  puts x 
  run_test 
}
```

Alternatively, using a [counting semaphore](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent/Semaphore.html), we can assign some priorities to the threads:

```
require 'concurrent-ruby'

def run_test
  mutex     = Mutex.new
  sync      = Concurrent::Semaphore.new(0)
  cond      = ConditionVariable.new
  cond_main = ConditionVariable.new
  threads   = []

  t1_done = false
  t2_done = false

  threads << Thread.new do
    mutex.synchronize do
      sync.release(1)
      # this needs to happen first
      cond.wait(mutex, 2)
      raise 'timeout waiting for switch' if !t2_done

      # some work
      t1_done = true
      cond.signal
    end
  end

  threads << Thread.new do
    sync.acquire(1)
    mutex.synchronize do
      cond.signal
      # some work
      t2_done = true
      cond.wait(mutex, 2)
      raise 'timeout waiting for switch' if !t1_done
    end
  end

  threads.map(&:join)
end

50000.times { |x| 
  puts x 
  run_test 
}
```

I prefer the second solution as it allows you to control the order of your threads, though it feels a little dirtier.

As a curiosity, on Ruby 2.6, your code does not seem to raise exceptions (tested >10M runs).